# Parsing User from json that has user object inside (with Codable)

Tags: json, swift, codable

Let's say that I have following User object:

```
struct User: Codable {
    let id: Int
}
```

And getting following json from an API:

```
{
    "user": {
        "id": "22"
    }
}
```

Obviously, the codable user wont parse. Is there any way how to do it, other than creating wrapper object? Thank you.

*Edit: I got some answers with wrappers - I know this approach, but I was curious about an alternative way. If it's better way to do it or not is irrelevant.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **`containers`** in `Codable` to get `nested data from JSON`.

**Containers = No Wrapper Object required**

```
struct User: Decodable {
    var id: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case user, id
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let user = try values.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self, forKey: .user)
        let idStr = try user.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
         id = Int(idStr) ?? 0
    }
}
```

Using `containers`, you can store the value of `id` using a `single object` instead of making any `wrapper object`.

**Note:** In `JSON` sample you provided `id` is of type `String`. But in the `struct` definition, you are using `id` of type `Int`. The code I've given is after converting `String to Int`. In case you made a typo, use the `string` value as it is.

**Suggestion** - Use `id` as `Int?` instead of `Int`. Its better to not store any value than storing a garbage one (Example: 0 in this case)

Comment: Why not use `decode(_:forKey:)` instead of `decodeIfPresent(_:forKey:)`? Then you don't need to make `id` optional nor give it a dummy value. Let it throw if it's missing.

Comment: And what if the api doesn’t give expected response? There might be other keys in the struct as well?

Comment: I think that depends upon how the User is expected to be in that particular usecase.

Comment: Given that the OP made `id` non-optional then it should be there and it would be an exception if it's not. Therefore `decode` is better than `decodeIfPresent`. The OP can catch the exception and handle the missing id as needed.

Comment: Okay. Corrected that.

Comment: @PGDev The huge benefit of non-optionals is you get a full-fledged error which tells you exactly what's going on. A backend change breaks your code anyway. With optionals and `decodeIfPresent` you get a lot of `nil` properties but you don't know why. With non-optionals you get a comprehensive error and you can fix the code in a few minutes.

Comment: @rmaddy json contains a String value for id and not the Int.

Answer (score 2):

Two mistakes: the root object is missing and the type of `id` is `String` (note the double quotes).

With `Codable` you have to parse the JSON always from the top

```
struct Root : Codable {
    let user : User
}

struct User : Codable {
    let id: String
}
```

Alternatively decode to a dictionary but this makes the usage of `Codable` pointless.

Comment: He asked how to do it _without_ a wrapper. However, a wrapper is BY FAR the easiest way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest model for your JSON:

```
import Foundation

// MARK: - UserModel
struct UserModel: Codable {
let user: User
}

// MARK: - User
struct User: Codable {
let id: String
}
```